Sump Pump on exterior perimeter of house to drain crawl space?
Hoping someone can clarify something for me. i am getting a sump pump installed in my crawl space (Pier & beam house) since we constantly get standing water under there. We got a couple of bids and both companies had the sump pump just outside the exterior of the house. I got the below comment from one of the companies I messaged regarding the sump pump being on the exterior of the crawl space instead of inside the  crawl space. I do live in the DFW, TX area and have some serious rough clay soil.
Is this normal practice and if so how would it drain the water from the flooded crawl space if the sump pump is on the exterior of the crawl space/house?

"The only times a sump pump is installed underneath the pier and beam is when there is a basement or when the pier and beam has more than 5Ft of space underneath. It works exactly the same but the only thing is when installing a sump on the exterior, we must have it right beside the perimeter beam, must be underground and have trenches dug under the pier and beam that slope towards the pump."


Pretty clear and logical explanation there. Rather than putting the pump in a hard to access and service location under the house with low clearance, the pump is put in an accessible  location and water from under the house is brought to it by appropriately sloped trenches.
